# how to add a subtext to a table cell?

Tags: iphone

i have created a table view which displays database fields.i need to add a sub-label and a subtext to each cell in which i can display other database fields. need help..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So you want the main text, and a subtitle.  Like in the music app?  If that's what you want, you want to set the style of the TableView to "UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle".  And then the way to set the main label;

`cellName.textLabel.text = @"label text"`

And to set the subtitle;

`cellName.detailTextLabel.text = @"subtitle text".`

Answer (score 1):

Add UILabel in the cell and assign text. you can add control in table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the three20 framework. It has a rich set of tablecell designs. Might be an overkill, but it as some other good stuff in too.